# Opening source files in eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I'm using the Team Foundation Server Plug-in for **Eclipse**.

When I double-click a file from the "Source Control" tab (or from the "Pending Changes" one), the file get opened into the system default text editor.

Is there a way to tell the tfs eclipse-plugin to open the file in Eclipse?

A workaround is just to set Eclipse as the system default editor for source files, but this is not what I'm looking for.

I'm using:
Eclipse Kepler

TFS plug-in for Eclipse v12.0.2

Lubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: I've never used the TFS plugin; can you right-click on the files in those views? Do you see the **Open With** pop-up menu option when you do?

Comment: @E-Riz Just **View** (in Source control) or **Open** (in Pending changes)...

Comment: That sounds like a really big hole in the TFS plugin, but maybe it's just asking your Eclipse workspace to open the files and they're not associated correctly in your preferences. What type(s) of files?

Comment: @E-Riz Files are .c, .h and .cpp. I got Eclipse CDT installed, but I don't know if they are associated correctly. I will check tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: I have one workspace that opens text files externally (notepad++) and another that opens them in eclipse. I cannot determine which setting is different between the two workspaces. They seem to be using the very same version of TFS plug-in. If I find it, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When viewing a file outside of the current workspace, the file will be edited with the associated system editor. Within the current workspace, the internal viewer should be used. This is my experience using:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

Comment: What do you mean by "outside" and "within the current workspace"? In my project, I have either *linked files* to files outside the workspace and *real files* within (subdirs of) the current workspace. When double-clicked from the pending changes view, both kinds of file open inside the system predefined editor. I run **Lubuntu** though, so maybe under windows the behavior is actually different.

Comment: I have several workspaces: One mapped to HEAD and others to various branches. The Pending Changes view shows all changes in all workspaces. The double-click behavior is different depending on whether the file clicked is in the branch mapped to the current workspace or in a branch not mapped to the current workspace.

Comment: Got it. I have just one workspace under TFS, the current one, though.